# Is a portable SSD USB 3.1 faster than a portable HDD USB 3.1?

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, usb-3

Is a high quality (Samsung/Transcend) portable SSD USB 3.1 drive faster than a cheaper portable HDD USB 3.1 drive (WD My Passport) when connected to a USB 3.0 port?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A typical HDD tops out at about 120 megabytes per second,compared with 500megabytes per second on an SSD. Also the latencies for random seeks is orders of magnitude faster on SSD because there us no need to wait for the disk to spin under the head.

USB3.0 is fast enough to support - or at least largely support the increased speeds of SSD (and gives a boost over USB2 for hdds as well)